# Extended Euclidean Algorithm: a remainder becomes zero

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

When working on the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I have stumbled upon this system of linear congruences.
$$
x\equiv2 \mbox{ mod 3}
$$
$$
x\equiv3 \mbox{ mod 5}
$$
$$
x\equiv4 \mbox{ mod 11}
$$
$$
x\equiv5 \mbox{ mod 16}
$$

Problem I am having is, when I apply the extended Euclidean Algorithm to find $M_2$ such that $N_2.M_2\equiv1\mbox{ mod }n_2$ (where $n_2=5$ and $N_2=3\times11\times16=528$ and $M_3$ being the modular inverse of 528 under $\mbox{ mod }5$), I reach the following.

$$
528=105\times5+3\\
105=35\times3+0
$$
What I don't understand is how to go from this point forth. This question might have been repeated somewhere in this stack exchange. But I am unable to find any such. That is why I have chosen to post this. Thanks n advance.

Comment: @GAVD Thanks for making it look better. :)

Comment: $528$ is not $105\times 5+30$.

Comment: Corrected. It was a typo..

Comment: Surely, the next stage in your EEE should be $5-1\times 3=2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your second equation should be $5 = 1 \cdot 3 + 2$ rather than $105 = 35 \cdot 3 + 0$.

Comment: Oh! I got it now.. :-? Thank you @N.F.Taussig...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is I am choosing the wrong input to the second iteration. I am choosing 105, which is the quotient of $528\div5$ as the dividend, whereas it should actually be 5, which is the divider of the previous iteration. So it actually should be

$$
528=105\times5+3\\
5=1\times3+2\\
3=1\times2+1
$$
and that's it. Thanks to @N.F.Taussig and @LordSharktheUnknown.